# Android - Google One Tap Sign In/up - Refresh token

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-signin, google-identity

I use [Google One Tap Sign in/up](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/overview) on my Android application. When the user logs in, the app receives an id token, which then is used for HTTP requests to my backend server for authentication and authorization.

That token works for about 1 hour. After that, it stops working and the user has to sign in again.

What can I use to maintain my user signed in? Does the same API (Google One Tap Sign in/up) is able to do that or do I have to use another one?

I also checked [Google OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app). Here, you do have access to the Refresh Token (this is what I'm looking for). However, at the beginning of the page, it recommends to use [Android Log In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start) (legacy version of Google One Tap Sign in/up):

> **Alternatives**
>
> For mobile apps, you may prefer to use Google Sign-in for Android or iOS. The Google Sign-in client libraries handle authentication and user authorization, and they may be simpler to implement than the lower-level protocol described here.

I'm able to use the Google OAuth 2.0 to achieve this, but I want to check first if I can use Google One Tap Sign in/up to achieve this, as stated on the website.

Thank you!

**UPDATE (03/29/23):**

I finally was able to maintain my user signed in seamlessly. Instead of using the new Google Sign in one tap, I used the legacy version of Google Sign In, which, at least for now, is more complete and has this function: [`silentSignIn()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInClient#silentSignIn()). The only drawback is that you only are able to get ID tokens.

However, since my server does the authorization part and only needs the authentication from Google, it works perfectly for me.

If there's a way to achieve this with One Tap, please let me know.

Thank you!